# If a windows folder has a dot/period in the name, file explorer search does not return results from that folder

Tags: windows-search

Common in development environment, some of my folders contain dots in the name.  like
c:\src\project1.ui.help.  I have set up the c:\src folder as indexed (with sub folders).

When I try to search in c:\ for a file or file contents that I know exist within this directory, windows (10 and 11) do not return those results.

Is there a work around?

Note - there are 100's of help articles about searching for a folder that has a dot in its name or starts with a dot - this is not the question.  I am searching for ordinary files  like "blah.cs" that are *within* a set of folders that have dots in their name.

**EDIT:**  To be clear, this occurs when there is more than one dot in the folder name.  e.g. searching for a file e.g. **"file.version.dll"** that exists in both **c:\src\netcoreapp3.1\** and **c:\src\my.project.name\** , only the result from the **c:\src\netcreapp3.1\** folder is returned in search.

Comment: These folders are on drives which have been indexed by Windows Search?  There is no specific reason these folders would act differently than folders without periods.

Comment: One thing I should be clear on - this happens when there is more than one dot in the name.  I'll edit the post

Comment: That does not answer my question if the folder is indexed or not.

Comment: See second sentence of line one. " I have set up the c:\src folder as indexed (with sub folders)."